# Refer to containing object from inside a method parameter object?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, anonymous-class, parameter-object

Not sure how to phrase the question to be technically correct, but suppose I have an object `(outer)` that has a method which takes another object `(inner)` as a parameter - how can I refer to `outer` from within `inner`?

To clarify what I mean, here's an example using an Android `EditText` and an implementation of `TextWatcher`:

```
EditText myEditText = getEditText();

myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // How can I refer to myEditText here in a more generic way than 
        // using myEditText directly?         
    }
});
```

In this example I could of course just use `myEditText` inside the `TextWatcher` implementation. But what I want to know is if there is a more generic way to get to the `"outer"` object from the `"inner"` in this case?

I know that one can use `MyClass.this` when dealing with anonymous inner classes, but that doesn't work in this case.

Comment: The `TextWatcher` interface doesn't pass the `View` into its methods like the `OnClickListener` interface, if that's what you're thinking of, so using a direct reference is about as good as you can do, unless you want to create your own class that implements `TextWatcher`, with methods that add a `View` parameter to the interface methods.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `myEditText` within the method? It's not clear what more generic way you want, given that `myEditText` is the only relevant variable here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was thinking of a construction similar to `MyClass.this` but that would work in this scenario. It's not that I don't want to use `myEditText` , just that I was curious if there was some more generic way to do it that I didn't know about, but I guess not.

Comment: That doesn't answer why you don't want to use the construction that *will* work, namely just using `myEditText`.